# How to update to the latest version of WordPress when running on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can find plenty of info on how to deploy WordPress on Elastic Beanstalk, but I haven't found much on keeping it up to date with the latest version.

Not knowing a great deal about WordPress I updated it like this:

1. Scaled Beanstalk back to single instance mode.
2. Updated WordPress through the WordPress UI (i.e. clicked the update button).
3. sshed to the now single Beanstalk instance.
4. Zipped up the WordPress directory (/var/app/current).
5. Downloaded the zip file.
6. Added my original .ebextensions to the zip file.
7. Modified the zip file to remove everything in wp-content/uploads (because that's a symbolic link to EFS).
8. Renamed the zip file and deployed it back to Beanstalk.
9. Scaled instances back out.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there a better/safer way?

Note: My initial beanstalk deplyment was basically [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html).